# Assuming that the Earth has no gravity, when the diameter of the Earth continues to increase outwards, will we feel that the Earth has gravity?

Tags: forces

Assuming that the Earth has no gravity, when the diameter of the Earth continues to increase outwards, will we feel that the Earth has gravity? At what speed does the Earth expand, we will get a $1g$ gravitational force?

Comment: Are you asking how rapidly the surface of an Earth sized sphere would have to accelerate outwards to give the impression of having the same gravity as the Earth? If so the answer is $g$ i.e. $9.81 m/s^2$.

Comment: You'd pretty quickly notice other towns getting further away. It would take just $19$ minutes of such expansion, starting now, to double Earth's current radius.

Comment: What you are asking about is commonly called the equivalence principle, where a person cannot differentiate between gravity and acceleration.  You will be able to find lots of videos on the equivalence principle.

Answer (score 1):

In other words...will you feel gravity in an elevator moving "up" in space? Only while it is accelerating "up" at 9.81m/s^2. Asking what speed is required misunderstands the problem; It's not about speed.

So Earth's diameter would need to be increasing at an *accelerating* rate of 9.81m/s^2. A constant expansion would not produce any feel of gravity.

Identical to how you only get pressed into a car seat while the car is accelerating.